VBA Access file extraction
I am trying to extrude the attachments from my access database into a temperarly folder with some details to make each file uniek. The script that ChatGPT provided did work and extracted them but all of the files went corrupt and I can no longer open any file. Word fixes itself but the rest of the zip, xls, xlsx, jpg, jpeg, png, etc files are corrupt.
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub ExportAttachments()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsEmployees As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsPictures As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strFolderPath As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strOrdernr As String
    Dim strSerienr As String
    Dim strMeld_dd As String
    Dim strCountry As String
    Dim stm As Object
    Dim errorLogFileName As String
    Dim errorLogNum As Integer
    
    ' Set the folder path where you want to save the attachments
    strFolderPath = "C:\Users\rijken.b\Documents\test\2023 vervolg\"
    
    ' Ensure the folder exists, if not, create it
    If Dir(strFolderPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir strFolderPath
    End If
    
    ' Set the current database
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    
    ' Open the parent recordset
    Set rsEmployees = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM `Planning 2023 vervolg`")
    
    ' Initialize error logging
    errorLogFileName = strFolderPath & "ErrorLog.txt"
    errorLogNum = FreeFile
    On Error Resume Next
    Open errorLogFileName For Append As errorLogNum
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error creating error log file: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation
        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Close errorLogNum
    
    ' Loop through the employee records
    Do While Not rsEmployees.EOF
        ' Check if the field "Field1" is not empty
        If Not IsNull(rsEmployees("Field1")) Then
            ' Open the attachment recordset
            Set rsPictures = rsEmployees.Fields("Field1").Value
            
            ' Get the necessary values for the current row
            strOrdernr = Nz(rsEmployees.Fields("Ordernr:").Value, "NAN")
            strSerienr = Nz(rsEmployees.Fields("Serienr").Value, "NAN")
            strMeld_dd = Nz(Format(rsEmployees.Fields("Meld dd").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd"), "NAN") ' Format date explicitly
            strCountry = Nz(rsEmployees.Fields("Country").Value, "NAN")
            
            ' Loop through the attachments
            Do While Not rsPictures.EOF
                On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
                ' Get the file name and modify it to include Ordernr, Serienr, meld_dd, and Country
                strFileName = strFolderPath & strOrdernr & "_" & strSerienr & "_" & strMeld_dd & "_" & strCountry & "_" & rsPictures.Fields("FileName").Value
                
                ' Initialize ADODB stream
                Set stm = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
                stm.Type = 1 ' Binary data type
                stm.Open
                stm.Write rsPictures.Fields("FileData").Value
                stm.SaveToFile strFileName, 2 ' Save binary data to file (2 means overwrite if exists)
                stm.Close
                Set stm = Nothing
                Debug.Print "Exported file: " & strFileName
                
                rsPictures.MoveNext
                On Error GoTo 0
            Loop
        End If
        rsEmployees.MoveNext
    Loop
    
    ' Clean up
    rsEmployees.Close
    Set rsPictures = Nothing
    Set rsEmployees = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    
    ' Display completion message
    MsgBox "Attachments exported successfully!"
    
    ' Check if any errors were logged
    If Dir(errorLogFileName) <> "" And FileLen(errorLogFileName) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Errors occurred during export. Check the error log for details: " & errorLogFileName, vbExclamation
    End If
    Exit Sub
    
ErrorHandler:
    ' Log error to file
    WriteErrorLog errorLogFileName, "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") at file: " & strFileName
    Err.Clear ' Clear the error for next iteration
    Resume Next
End Sub

Private Sub WriteErrorLog(ByVal fileName As String, ByVal errorDetails As String)
    ' Open the error log file and write error details
    Dim errorLogNum As Integer
    errorLogNum = FreeFile
    On Error Resume Next
    Open fileName For Append As errorLogNum
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        Print #errorLogNum, Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss") & " - " & errorDetails
        Close errorLogNum
    Else
        Debug.Print "Error writing to error log: " & Err.Description
        Close errorLogNum
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub


I have tried many efforts with chatgpt to get it resolved but everytime the files come out corrupt.
